# AngularJS $resource cache doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, caching, angularjs-resource

I'm trying to add caching to a `$resource` in Angular, but no matter what I try (so far), Angular always ends up performing a full requests and the server happily returns a full response.

Simplified, my `$resource` looks like this:

```
app.factory("Brands", ["$resource", "JsonCache", function($resource, JsonCache) {
  return $resource("/api/car_brands", {
    query: {
      method: "GET",
      isArray: true,
      cache: JsonCache
    }
  });
}]);
```

The `JsonCache` is made like this:

```
app.factory('JsonCache', function ($cacheFactory) {
  return $cacheFactory('json-cache');
});
```

I've also tried with `cache: true` but doesn't help.

I'm using Angular 1.3.2 and Angular-resource 1.3.2.

Server returns these headers:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 03 Dec 2014 16:20:59 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

I see no cache-specific headers, but when I tell Angular to cache the things, I'd expect it to cache, no matter what. Also I have no way of modifying these headers, so I have to deal with it.

I can't find any other details in the documentation that tell me there's anything else I need to set up (such as, I dunno, TTL?) so I can only assume that it should "just work". But why isn't it? What did I miss?